# Bind an unbind event with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

while clicking on anchor tag i am unbinding the click event and performing my action but after performing my action i want to bind the same event that i had unbind and i really don't know which event was that how i can bind that again.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
              /*unbinding the kudos action*/
                $(".lia-link-navigation.kudos-link").unbind();
              $('.lia-link-navigation.kudos-link').click(function(e){
                    console.log('kudo is clicked');
                      if(title == ''){

                      //something

                     }else{
                      $(this).bind('click');
                     }
                });
  });
```

Comment: Create function to handle events-`handler`, ` $('.lia-link-navigation.kudos-link').click(handler);` and to bind it again `$(this).click(handler);`

Comment: handler? i am not familiar with handler

Comment: That's the name of function, you'll create to handle the events instead of anonymous function

Comment: the problem is that i don't know which function is working. that why i unbind everything. and i want to bind it again if my condition fails

Comment: You've missed `});` of `ready`

Comment: From my thought, its the bad code

Answer (score 0):

declare your function and when you want to bind it again to same function use its name.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    click_function = function (e) {
        console.log('kudo is clicked');
        if (title == '') {
            //something
        } else {
            $(this).bind('click');
        }
    };



    //bind the event for first time or any time that you want to bind the event. 
    $('.lia-link-navigation.kudos-link').click(click_function);

   //un-bind event. 
   $(".lia-link-navigation.kudos-link").unbind();
});
```

Comment: But its not the best practice for every click, binding the event and unbind the event. When ur application running android native browser or ipad u will realize that.

Comment: may i know, y u r unbinding after click the anchor tag

Comment: i don't think the code have correct logic, but i want to use same code and answer how bind and unbind event to same function.

Comment: @omidam81: First we need a understand the problem and way of coding and what he is asking

Comment: if you check the edited code (on question) then you will found out what was problem,

Comment: @albert-jegani also this pseudo code, and its not doing any things.

Comment: same problem again . :) it doesn't bind the function if once i unbind. 

if title is not blank it doesn't bind the function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lia-link-navigation.kudos-link').click(function (e) {
        if (title == '')
        {
            // PREVENT LINK FROM OPENING IF TITLE IS BLANK
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: i know bro its missing but thats not the problem the problem is that i cant bind the function if i unbind it once because i dont knw the function name.

Comment: You want that if title is blank then link should not be opened by clicking on anchor tag.Am I right ?

Comment: no you are not right . some other jquery function is running on that click i dnt know where that function i defined , i don't want it to run if title is blank and if it is not blank i want it to run.

Answer (score 0):

you can stop the propagation of the event so that the other handlers does not get fired.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      /*unbinding the kudos action*/

      $('.lia-link-navigation.kudos-link').click(function(e){
            console.log('kudo is clicked');
              if(title == ''){
              e.stopImmediatePropagation()
             }
        });
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3p5aj5/)

Comment: both function are working this one two and the other function to that i want to stop

Comment: try putting this click event above the other click events